# ImportError: cannot import name 'YouTube'

Tags: python

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Youtube.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytube import YouTube
ImportError: cannot import name 'YouTube'
```

how to debug this?

any ssuggestions

Comment: have you installed all the requirements needed first?

Comment: installing [pytube3](https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/) worked for me

Comment: what are the requirements?

Comment: Since you are trying to import from the pytube library, having that library installed is a requirement.  It doesn't automatically come with a basic Python installation.  Have you installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you've not installed `pytube`

#### How to do this?

**On Windows**

1. Press `Win+R`
2. Type `cmd`
3. You will get terminal, type there: `pip install pytube3 --user`
4. Wait a bit while the process finishes.

**On Linux**

1. Find the `Terminal` app in search
2. Open it
3. Type in terminal `pip install pytube3 --user`
4. Wait while the process finishes.

Or, you can read [official tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)
Probably this helps.

Comment: pip install YouTube
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement YouTube (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for YouTube

Comment: You should type `pip install pytube3`, not `pip install Youtube`.